# ansible pass shell command result to variable

Tags: ansible

I stuck a bit with ansible and autogenerated id, I have multiple mysql master - slaves server for that I need to generate a server-id.

my idea was to do something like this:

```
   - name: generate repli-id
      shell: hostname -I | sed -e 's/ \+\([a-z0-9]\+\:\)\+[a-z0-9]\+//' | sed -e 's/ /\n/' | grep -v '^$' | tail -1 | awk -F. '{print $3 * 256 + $4}'
      register:  slave_repli

    - debug: var=slave_repli.stdout_lines

    - name: rewrite
      template: src=templates/root.j2 dest=/root/test.conf
```

so I get the id generated

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
task path: /Users/miwi/ansible/roles/test/main.yml:32
ok: [mysqls5slave] => {
    "slave_repli.stdout_lines": [
        "3698"
    ]
}
ok: [mysqls5master] => {
    "slave_repli.stdout_lines": [
        "3699"
    ]
}
```

my question is now how do I pass it over to my var file

slave_server_id: {{ slave_server_id }}

Answer (score 1):

You could use the copy module in addition with local_action to save the variable to a local file on your control machine and use it later on your next playbook:

```
- local_action: copy content="slave_server_id: {{ slave_repli.stdout_lines[0] }}" dest=/path/to/var/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating your ID from within your playbook, this is where you may want to define a custom fact. On your mysql server, you'ld do something like this:

```
mkdir -p /etc/ansible/facts.d
cat <<EOF >/etc/ansible/facts.d/mysql.fact
#!/bin/sh
echo "[mysql]"
echo server_id=`hostname -I | sed -e 's/ \+\([a-z0-9]\+\:\)\+[a-z0-9]\+//' | sed -e 's/ /\n/' | grep -v '^$' | tail -1 | awk -F. '{print $3 * 256 + $4}'`
EOF
chmod +x /etc/ansible/facts.d/mysql.fact
```

Run `ansible -m setup your.mysql.ip.address` to make sure your fact is properly executed. You should have some `ansible_local['mysql']['mysql']['server_id']` defined.

Say you'ld want ansible to deploy this fact, you may do something like:

```
- name: install fact
  copy: src=myfact dest=/etc/ansible/facts.d/mysql.fact owner=root group=root mode=0755
  register: fact_installed
- name: reload facts
  setup: filter=ansible_local
  when: fact_installed is defined and fact_installed.changed == True
```

After which, you may include your template, referring to your `server_id` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to use the generated value in your template:

**Option 1:** Use `slave_repli.stdout_lines` in your template:

```
# in templates/root.j2:
...
slave_server_id: {{ slave_repli.stdout_lines[0] }}
...
```

**Option 2:** Assign a variable

In your playbook:

```
- name: rewrite
  vars:
    slave_server_id: "{{ slave_repli.stdout_lines[0] }}"
  template:
    src: templates/root.j2
    dest: /root/test.conf
```

In your template:

```
# in templates/root.j2:
...
slave_server_id: {{ slave_server_id }}
...
```

I prefer the second approach as it's much cleaner.